# ParametricNDSolve and Plot

Tags: differential-equations

with your help I have obtained the Numerical solution of ODE problem

```
CovariantDM = DM'[t] + 3 a'[t]/a[t] DM[t] + Q[t];
CovariantDE = DE'[t] + 3 a'[t]/a[t] DE[t] (1 + w[t]) - Q[t];
Gattopardo = w'[t]*Q[t] + DE[t]*w[t];
Q[t] = DM[t]*a'[t]/a[t];
{DMsol, DEsol, wsol} = NDSolveValue[{CovariantDE == 0, CovariantDM == 0, Gattopardo == 0, DM[0] == 0.25, DE[0] == 0.7, w[0] == -1}, {DM, DE, w}, {t, -0.93, 0.93}]
```

where a[t] has been obtained in a previous step. The solution is
[image]

which looks to be fine. Now, I would like to see different solutions if I change some parameter, so I tried with

```
{DMsol, DEsol, wsol} = ParametricNDSolve[{Q[t] == c*a'[t]/a[t], CovariantDE == 0, CovariantDM == 0, Gattopardo == 0, DM[0] == 0.25, DE[0] == 0.7, w[0] == -0.85}, {DM, DE, w}, {t, -0.93, 0.93}, {c}]
Plot[Evaluate[Table[wsol[c][t], {c, -1, 1, .3}]], {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and as result I obtain
[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestions from the program (errors, warning etc.). I would like to solve parametrically my ODEs, but I don't know what to do. Can you help me?

Comment: Two different definitions of one function Q[t] are given. It is necessary to delete one of them or put `DM[t]=c`.

Comment: I found the mistake: I defined the output of ParametricNDSolve as if it was ParametricNDSolveValue...

Comment: ...however, thank you so much for your help!